C substring of variable length in a consistent file format
I have the following line from a file:
Name:   variable_length_string

and I'd like to extract the substring:
variable_length_string

from it. This is what I have:
  char* getProcStatus(const char* path) {
      printf("path: %s", path);
      char* chrptr_ProcessStatus = NULL;
      FILE* fd_status = fopen (path, "rt");
      char line[300];
      char name[5];                                                                                                                                                                           
   
      char* procName = NULL;
      if ( fd_status ) {
          if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd_status) != NULL) {
              sscanf(line, "%s%s", name, procName);
              if (procName != NULL) {
                  printf("%s", procName);
                  fclose(fd_status);
                  return procName;
              }
          }
      }

      return procName;
  }

I tried creating a name buffer just to store away the "Name: " somewhere but it isn't working at all (if (procName != NULL)) isnt executing.
How do I get a substring of variable length? All I know is that it ends with '\n' and the line will always begin with 'Next: '
EDIT:
I realized my mistake was that I didn't allocate mem for procName, adding this line fixes the issue:
procName = malloc(200);

But I still haven't figured out how to grab the entire string until a newline character because the variable_length_string might be "variable length string" and have spaces in it.
I guess I'm asking if regex is possible within sscanf to do a regex match to something like this:
[a-zA-Z\-\/]*$


OK firstly you are reading the line data into line which is on the stack and you are returning a pointer to it.  When the function goes out-of-scope the stack is reclaimed.  Instead, you will need to strdup() it and the caller will need to free() it.

@trojanfoe: The code does not return a pointer to line.

@EricPostpischil Indeed; however that is clearly the intention.

The intention is to return procName, not the entire line read in by fgets, as per the "return procName"

@trojanfoe: It is not clearly the intention. It is apparent that OP expects that, after sscanf(line, "%s%s", name, procName);, procName will contain a pointer to the desired data. There is no indication of whether they expect this to ve a pointer into line or a pointer to newly allocated memory. (There are sscanf extensions that allocate memory this way, given a suitable conversion specification, although they of course require that &procName is passed, not procName. OP’s code cannot work with either expectation.)

@EricPostpischil Well it was clear to me at least.  Why don't you address your comments to the OP and get off my back?

<O/T> no need for both returns with the code presented, you're not in a loop (maybe you should be?). The last return will hit immediately after fclose

Why not just use strtok(line, ":") to split the "name" and "data"? After that, use a simple function to strip leading and trailing space from both strings. I've done it maybe hundreds of times, and it works very well.

@Someprogrammerdude I didn't even know about that func...could you post it as an answer with the fn to strip leading and trailing spaces?

@trojanfoe: Because the assertion in your comment is in fact not clear and hence can lead OP and others down an incorrect line of reasoning, so that should be pointed out. There is no reason your comments should be immune from criticism and correction.

Or is the problem that you don't know if fgets have read the whole line? Then you have two options: 1) Read character by character into an array that you allocate and reallocate as needed, until you get the newline (or EOF); Or 2) Use fgets to read in a loop, until it has read the full line (which can be detected by it either returning NULL or that the string ends with a newline). As before, allocated and reallocate memory as needed.

fgets definitely reads the whole line (atleast in my case) but now that i think about it, that's a good idea because these procNames would surpass 500 chars, I think

When I need to read key-value data from a file (or somewhere else), I usually use the strtok function to split the key and the data into separate strings.
You will likely need to strip leading and trailing spaces for both the key and the data.
A possible solution would then be something like this:
// Take a pointer to the first character in a string, and returns
// a pointer to the first non-space character of it
// Effectively "stripping" leading space
static char *strip_leading(char *str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;  // Just to be safe

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; isspace(str[i]) != 0; ++i)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    // Here the variable i will be the index of the first non-space character
    return &str[i];
}

// Skips over all trailing spaces in a null-terminated string,
// and set the null-terminator at the last of those
// Effectively "stripping" all trailing space
static char *strip_trailing(char *str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str);

    if (str == NULL || length == 0)
        return NULL;  // Just to be safe

    char *last = &str[length - 1];

    for (; isspace(*last); --last)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    // Here last will point to the last non-space character of the string
    *(last + 1) = '\0';  // Replace next (space) character with the terminator

    // Return a pointer to the beginning of the string
    return str;
}

// Strip both leading and trailing space from a string
static char *strip(char *str)
{
    return strip_leading(strip_trailing(str));
}

struct data
{
    char *key;
    char *value;
};

// This function takes a "line" of input, and extracts the "key" and "value" from it
// Returns a structure holding the key and value as strings
static struct data get_key_value(char *line, const char *separator)
{
    if (separator == NULL)
    {
        // No separator provided, default to ':'
        separator = ":";
    }

    // Get the key
    char *key = strtok(line, separator);
    if (key == NULL)
    {
        // Error, return a structure with null key/data pointers
        return (struct data){ NULL, NULL };
    }

    // Get the value
    char *value = strtok(NULL, "");  // Use "" as the separator to read until the end
    if (value == NULL)
    {
        // Error, return a structure with null key/data pointers
        return (struct data){ NULL, NULL };
    }

    // Strip leading and trailing spaces from both key and value
    key = strip(key);
    value = strip(value);

    // Return a structure with *duplicates* of the key and value
    // Those need to be passed to `free` once done with them
    return (struct data){ strdup(key), strdup(value) };
}

// Finally a function to read all the input from the file
static void get_all_key_value(FILE *file)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    char line[512];  // No need to be greedy about the space

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {
        char *linep = strip_leading(line);

        // If the first non-space character is a '#', then this line is a comment
        if (linep[0] == '#')
        {
            continue;  // Continue with the next line
        }

        // Now get the key and value from the line
        struct data data = get_key_value(linep, NULL);

        // TODO: Do something with the returned structure!
    }
}

Here is an example of the above code, reading lines from stdin.

thank you! can you explain this line:     return (struct data){ strdup(key), strdup(value) }, why create the duplicates?

@Mathew Because the function doesn't know the life-time of the original string passed in to the get_key_value function. This way the returned structure becomes independent of the file and the data read from the file, and you can use it long after the file-reading function have ended.

ahhh okay, understood, thank you! I'm using the above code (I hope you don't mind) and I was wondering how I might echo a file into the program after I've compiled it. I've tried echo /proc/[PID]/status > ./strip (strip here being the compiled output) but no luck

@Mathew The > operation is redirection to file. It will overwrite the file. And echo will print the argument as a string, so echo /proc/[PID]/status will write /proc/[PID]/status to the standard output. What you should use is the cat command and piping: cat /proc/[PID]/status | ./strip. Remember to rebuild the program, since your previous redirection overwrote it.


something like this: [a-zA-Z\-\/]*$

Scan the string with "%*[-/a-zA-Z]" and perform error checks.

Put '-' first in the scanset.

No need to escape /.

Use * to scan, but not save.

Use "%n" to record offsets.

Lead with "Name: "  to scan keyword and consume option white-space.

The scanning only determines the offset of length of the desired token.  Later code allocates memory and copies it.
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd_status) != NULL) {
      int *start;
      int *end = 0;
      sscanf(line, "Name: %n%*[-/a-zA-Z]%n", &start, &end);
      if (end == 0 || line[end+1] != '\n') {
        Handle_incomplete_scan();
      }

      // Since 'end' is not 0, scan completed. 
      size_t len = (size_t) (end - start);
      char *procName = malloc(len + 1);
      if (procName == NULL) {
        Handle_out_of_memory();
      }

      memcpy(procName, line + start, len);
      procName[len] = '\0';

      // Use string in procName

      // Free when done
      free(procName);




This is a followup to my answer on your previous question: C program to sum up total mem usage of any proc
A few issues ...

(As mentioned by others) the code has to use strdup because the buffer is stack based.
The syntax has a colon (:): Sym    :   Val
The code doesn't select any given symbol


Here is a sample program. It is a rewrite in C of some perl code I've had lying around:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DVAL_BAD        (1LL << 62)

typedef long long s64;
struct symval {
    const char *sym;
    const char *val;
    s64 dval;
};

// sysproc_status -- load up data from /proc/<pid>/status
struct symval *
sysproc_status(pid_t pid)
{
    char file[100];
    char buf[1000];
    char *sym;
    char *val;
    int symcount = 0;
    struct symval *symlist = NULL;

    do {
        // open the file -- bug out on error
        sprintf(file,"/proc/%d/status",pid);
        FILE *xf = fopen(file,"r");
        if (xf == NULL)
            break;

        // read in all lines
        // FORMAT:
        // Sym     :      Value
        while (1) {
            // get next line
            sym = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf);
            if (sym == NULL)
                break;

            // strip newline
            buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

            // look for ":" separater
            val = strchr(buf,':');
            if (val == NULL)
                continue;
            *val = 0;

            // remove trailing whitespace from symbol
            for (sym = val - 1;  sym >= buf;  --sym) {
                if (! isspace(*sym))
                    break;
                *sym = 0;
            }
            sym = buf;

            // remove leading whitespace from value
            for (val += 1;  *val != 0;  ++val) {
                if (! isspace(*val))
                    break;
            }

            // increase size of list
            symlist = realloc(symlist,sizeof(*symlist) * (symcount + 1 + 1));
            if (symlist == NULL) {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(1);
            }

            // save data
            struct symval *symcur = &symlist[symcount++];
            symcur->sym = strdup(sym);
            symcur->val = strdup(val);

            // a convenience: get binary value
            if (isdigit(*val))
                symcur->dval = strtoll(val,&val,10);
            else
                symcur->dval = DVAL_BAD;

            // add EOT
            ++symcur;
            symcur->sym = NULL;
            symcur->val = NULL;
        }

        fclose(xf);
    } while (0);

    return symlist;
}

// sysproc_delete -- delete symbol list
void
sysproc_delete(struct symval *symlist)
{
    struct symval *symcur;

    do {
        if (symlist == NULL)
            break;

        for (symcur = symlist;  symcur->sym != NULL;  ++symcur) {
            free((void *) symcur->sym);
            free((void *) symcur->val);
        }

        free(symlist);
    } while (0);
}

// symval_print -- print a single key/value pair
void
symval_print(const struct symval *symcur)
{
    printf("%s: '%s'",symcur->sym,symcur->val);
    if (symcur->dval != DVAL_BAD)
        printf(" (%lld)",symcur->dval);
    printf("\n");
}

// sysproc_print -- print all list values
void
sysproc_print(const struct symval *symlist)
{
    const struct symval *symcur = symlist;

    if (symcur != NULL) {
        for (;  symcur->sym != NULL;  ++symcur)
            symval_print(symcur);
    }
}

// sysproc_find -- find a given entry by symbol name
const struct symval *
sysproc_find(const struct symval *symlist,const char *sym)
{
    const struct symval *symcur = symlist;
    const struct symval *symret = NULL;

    for (;  symcur->sym != NULL;  ++symcur) {
        if (strcmp(symcur->sym,sym) == 0) {
            symret = symcur;
            break;
        }
    }

    return symret;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    pid_t pid;
    if (argc > 0)
        pid = atoi(*argv);
    else
        pid = getpid();

    struct symval *symlist = sysproc_status(pid);
    sysproc_print(symlist);

    printf("\n");
    const struct symval *find = sysproc_find(symlist,"VmSize");
    if (find != NULL)
        symval_print(find);

    sysproc_delete(symlist);

    return 0;
}


Here is the output:
Name: 'procstatus'
Umask: '0022' (22)
State: 'R (running)'
Tgid: '3077758' (3077758)
Ngid: '0' (0)
Pid: '3077758' (3077758)
PPid: '5951' (5951)
TracerPid: '0' (0)
Uid: '1000  1000    1000    1000' (1000)
Gid: '1000  1000    1000    1000' (1000)
FDSize: '64' (64)
Groups: '470 1000 ' (470)
NStgid: '3077758' (3077758)
NSpid: '3077758' (3077758)
NSpgid: '3077758' (3077758)
NSsid: '5951' (5951)
VmPeak: '2516 kB' (2516)
VmSize: '2300 kB' (2300)
VmLck: '0 kB' (0)
VmPin: '0 kB' (0)
VmHWM: '756 kB' (756)
VmRSS: '756 kB' (756)
RssAnon: '64 kB' (64)
RssFile: '688 kB' (688)
RssShmem: '4 kB' (4)
VmData: '176 kB' (176)
VmStk: '132 kB' (132)
VmExe: '8 kB' (8)
VmLib: '1460 kB' (1460)
VmPTE: '40 kB' (40)
VmSwap: '0 kB' (0)
HugetlbPages: '0 kB' (0)
CoreDumping: '0' (0)
THP_enabled: '1' (1)
Threads: '1' (1)
SigQ: '0/47763' (0)
SigPnd: '0000000000000000' (0)
ShdPnd: '0000000000000000' (0)
SigBlk: '0000000000000000' (0)
SigIgn: '0000000000000000' (0)
SigCgt: '0000000000000000' (0)
CapInh: '0000000000000000' (0)
CapPrm: '0000000000000000' (0)
CapEff: '0000000000000000' (0)
CapBnd: '0000003fffffffff' (3)
CapAmb: '0000000000000000' (0)
NoNewPrivs: '0' (0)
Seccomp: '0' (0)
Speculation_Store_Bypass: 'thread vulnerable'
Cpus_allowed: 'ff'
Cpus_allowed_list: '0-7' (0)
Mems_allowed: '00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001' (0)
Mems_allowed_list: '0' (0)
voluntary_ctxt_switches: '0' (0)
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: '0' (0)

VmSize: '2300 kB' (2300)


Thank you! I will definitely inspect and try my best to follow that, really appreciate the time you spent! Seeing how other more experienced coders write is so useful for someone learning for the first time

I don't think sscanf (line, "%s%s", ... will do as you expect.  The first %s will probably load the entire line into the first argument.
In the code below, I search for the : character, then increment the pointer past any spaces.   strdup is used to allocate a pointer that can be returned.   Additional enhancements might be to trim any trailing spaces from the line.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
getProcStatus (const char* path) {
  FILE  * fd_status = fopen (path, "rt");
  char  line [300];
  char  * procName = NULL;
  const char  * tptr;

  printf ("path: %s\n", path);

  if ( fd_status ) {
    if (fgets (line, sizeof(line), fd_status) != NULL) {
//      sscanf (line, "%s%s", name, procName);
      tptr = strchr (line, ':');
      if (tptr == NULL) {
        fclose (fd_status);
        return NULL;
      }
      ++tptr;
      while (*tptr == ' ') {
        ++tptr;
      }
      if (*tptr == '\n' || *tptr == '\0') {
        fclose (fd_status);
        return NULL;
      }
      procName = strdup (tptr);
      size_t len = strlen (procName);
      if (len > 0 && procName [len - 1] == '\n') {
        procName [len - 1] = '\0';
      }
      printf ("procname: %s\n", procName);
    }
  }

  fclose (fd_status);
  return procName;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  char    *str;

  str = getProcStatus ("zz.txt");
  if (str != NULL) {
    free (str);
  }
}


I made an edit to my original post, allocating mem solved the issue, sscanf will populate the provided buffers and discard the rest so sscanf(line, "%s%s", name, extra) will populate name with "Name: " and extra with "extra" if the line is "Name: extra", space being the default delimiter. Now I'm trying to see if regex is possible

I rarely use the scanf family, which explains my ignorance.  As noted in the comments, strtok (strtok_r is better) is very useful.

Or I could be the ignorant one for using scanf instead of strtok ;P
